# How to get all integers/floor positions inside a "voxel-shaped" geometry

Tags: mesh, scripting, geometry

I need to store in a file all the "floor" positions that are inside a  "voxel-shaped" geometry. All geometries are dimensioned as if they were composed of a multitude of 1x1x1 voxels, but they really are in reality only one object. Also, all edges are parallel to the x,y, or z axes, and all corners are on integers coordinates.
For example, if I have a cube with dimensions 2x2x2, aligned with the XYZ axis, starting from [0,0,0]. But with a missing voxel between [1,1,1] and [2,2,2].
I need the positions : [0,0,0], [1,0,0],[0,0,1], [1,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,1,0],[0,1,1].
But, it could be more complicated geometries like "Minecraft-like" houses.

Comment: The coordinates you provided are of the 8 3D corners of the voxel cube, within the 2x2x2 cube (see image link below). Is this what you're aiming for? https://pasteboard.co/ItlIoRdkzNcF.png

Comment: It is nearly that. To be more precise it is the corner With the smallest coordinate of the 8 voxel inside the cube. Son a voxel that go from 1-1-1 to 2-2-2. We should get his position at 1-1-1

Comment: Please add information to your question about how what kind of output you would expect in a rotated object, non-cube objects, larger objects, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I edited the question. Hope it is complete enough now.